# OpenGL error with translation, C1068 and C2003

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, translation, glm-math

I've started a tutorial on OpenGL and this lesson is about translation of a triangle using `glm`. However, whenever I compile the program the following errors come up

> ```
> 0(9) : error C1068: too much data in type constructor
> (0) : error C2003: incompatible options for link`.
> ```

Again I am new to OpenGL and 
this tutorial is with Version 3.6 and I am on 4.6 so I don't know if that might be a problem, here's the code hope you could help me out (all on one page btw).

```cpp
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp"

#include <iostream>


//Window dimensions
const GLint SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 900;

GLuint VAO, VBO, shader, uniformModel;

bool isMovingLeft = true; 
float triOffset = 0.f;
float triMaxOffset = 0.7;
float triIncrement = 0.005;



//Vertex shader
static const char* vShader = "\n\
    #version 460 \n\
    \n\
    layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos; \n\
    \n\
    uniform mat4 model; \n\
    \n\
    void main() { \n\
        gl_Position = vec4(0.4 * pos.x + model, 0.4 * pos.y, pos.z, 1.0); \n\
    }; \n\
";

//Fragment shader
static const char* fShader = "\n\
    #version 460 \n\
    \n\
    out vec4 color; \n\
    \n\
    void main() { \n\
        color = vec4(0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.f); \n\
    }; \n\
";


void createTriangle() {
    //Vertices of the triangle 
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.f, -1.f, 0.f,
         1.f, -1.f, 0.f,
         0.f,  1.f, 0.f
    };

    //Binding it
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);


    //Information
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


    //Unbinding
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

}

void addShader(GLuint theProgram, const char* shaderCode, GLenum shaderType) {
    GLuint theShader = glCreateShader(shaderType);

    const GLchar* theCode[1];
    theCode[0] = shaderCode;

    GLint codeLength[1];
    codeLength[0] = strlen(shaderCode);

    glShaderSource(theShader, 1, theCode, codeLength);
    glCompileShader(theShader);


    //Getting error information for linking
    GLint result = 0;
    GLchar eLog[1024] = { 0 };

    glGetProgramiv(theShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (result != GL_FALSE) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(theShader, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        std::cout << "Error compiling the " << shaderType << ' ' << eLog << '\n';
    }


    glAttachShader(theProgram, theShader);

}

void compileShaders() {
    shader = glCreateProgram();

    if (shader != GL_TRUE) {
        std::cout << "Shader program error!\n";
    }

    //Adding shaders
    addShader(shader, vShader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    addShader(shader, fShader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    //Getting error information for linking
    GLint result = 0;
    GLchar eLog[1024] = { 0 };

    //Linking shader
    glLinkProgram(shader);

    //Shader linking status
    glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);
    if (result != GL_TRUE) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        std::cout << "Error linking program! " << eLog << '\n';
    }


    //Gets shader ID and then combines `uniformModel` with `model`
    uniformModel = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "model");
}


int main() {
    //Initialize GLFW
    if (glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE) {
        std::cout << "GLFW init failed\n";
        glfwTerminate();
    }


    //Setup GLFW window properties
    //OpenGL version
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4); //Large version
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 4); //Small version 
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //Detects any old OpenGL code, this will throw an error
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); //Allows forward compatibility (between differnt OS) 


    //Creating window
    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "OpenGL Test Window", NULL, NULL);
    glfwSetWindowPos(window, 250, 100);

    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "GLFW window creation failed!\n";
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    //Get buffer size information
    int bufferWidth, bufferHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &bufferWidth, &bufferHeight);

    //Set context for GLEW to use (can change between which window)
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //Allow modern extension features
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;


    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout << "Glew init failed!\n";
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        glfwTerminate();
    }


    //Setup viewport size
    glViewport(0, 0, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);

    createTriangle();
    compileShaders();


    //Main game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        //Get + Handle user input events
        glfwPollEvents();

        if (isMovingLeft) {
            triOffset += triIncrement;
        }
        else {
            triOffset -= triIncrement;
        }

        if (abs(triOffset) >= triMaxOffset) {
            isMovingLeft = !isMovingLeft;
        }


        //Clear window
        glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shader);

        //Matrix 4x4
        glm::mat4 model;
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(triOffset, triOffset, 0.f));

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformModel, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));


        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glUseProgram(0);


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uniform `model` is of type `mat4`. You've to transform the vertex coordinate by the matrix in the vertex shader:

<s>`gl_Position = vec4(0.4 * pos.x + model, 0.4 * pos.y, pos.z, 1.0);`</s>`

```c
gl_Position = model * vec4(0.4 * pos.x, 0.4 * pos.y, pos.z, 1.0);
```

You didn't get the error, because there is an issue in `addShader`. The compile errors of a shader object can be get by [`glGetShaderiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShader.xhtml) rather than [`glGetProgramiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetProgramiv.xml). If the shader is compiled successfully, then the result is `GL_TRUE` rather than `GL_FALSE`:

```cpp
glGetShaderiv(theShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
if (result != GL_TRUE) {
    glGetShaderInfoLog(theShader, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
    std::cout << "Error compiling the " << shaderType << ' ' << eLog << '\n';
}
```

---

Furthermore `glm::mat4 model;` gives an uninitialized matrix. To get an [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) you've to pass a single scalar (1.0) to the matrix constructor:

```cpp
glm::mat4 model(1.0f);
```

Comment: Thank you, it removed the errors however the triangle does not render to the screen?

Comment: @Legat Sorry, but I've tested your program and it works fine. I copied the code form the question and I applied the 3 suggested changes from the answer.

Comment: thank you, I didn't add the `(1.f) in the model for `glm::mat4`, do youhve a discord by any chance or something in case I get another error that I can't solve instead of having to put in in stackoverflow all the time? I don't have any OpenGL helpers :/

Comment: Okay, one question though really quick though, in the tutorial the following code is written as `glm::mat4 model;`, however you wrote it as `glm::mat4 model(1.f);` which solved the rendering issue. What does the 1.f do? I read online and it should've worked regardless putting the 1.f, so yeah?

Comment: @Legat `glm::mat4 model;` is an uninitialized matrix. `glm::mat4 model(1.f);` is a identity matrix (the values in the "diagonal" are 1). But I mentioned that in the answer.